# How to use the function only when it is called?

Tags: javascript

Sorry - i can not exactly explain the problem, so i show you an example.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var obj = new classs(2);
    alert(obj.x2);

    function classs(value){
        this.value = value;

        var multiplication = function(value, n){
            console.log(n);
            return parseInt(value) * parseInt(n);
        }

        this.x1 = multiplication(this.value, 1);
        this.x2 = multiplication(this.value, 2);
        this.x3 = multiplication(this.value, 3);
    }
}
```

So i call only `obj.x2`, but `console.log(n);` prints 3 times. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean you want to call `window.onload`, so that the calculation can be performed?

Answer (score 3):

Reading the `x2` property doesn't cause anything to be logged to the console, it will only read the already calculated value.

The properties `x1`, `x2` and `x3` are calculated when the `classs` object is created, so the values are logged to the console before you read the `x2` property. If you comment out the line that uses the `x2` property, the values will still be logged.

---

If you want to do the calculation after the object is created, you need to use functions instead:

```
this.x2 = function() { multiplication(this.value, 2); }
```

Usage:

```
alert(obj.x2());
```

Answer (score 0):

because you simply make call of multiplication 3 times

when you create your object

```
var obj = new classs(2);
```

it execute code inside of it and as you can see there are 3 call of function "multiplication".

```
this.x1 = multiplication(this.value, 1);
this.x2 = multiplication(this.value, 2);
this.x3 = multiplication(this.value, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

When classs is executed, the multiplication function is executed three times when x1, x2, and x3 are set.  That's why console.log is hit 3 times.  The alert, on the other hand, only happens once since you call alert on obj.x2.